# FIXED: multipart/form-data html form sends .flac files to Google Speech-to-Text API, uploads files as x-flac?

Tags: express, audio, metadata, multipartform-data, google-speech-to-text-api

**The Fix**

```
await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(`./uploads/${filename}`, {
    gzip: false,
    metadata: {
      content_type : "audio/flac",
      originalMimeType: "audio/flac",
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
      uploadType: "multipart"      
    },
```

I'm not totally sure why this worked, but my instructor suggested making this change: set gzip: false. Now, this successfully transcribes short and long audio from the bucket. It may have been an issue with content-encoding.

**The Previous Issue**

I am making a speech-to-text express app in Node.js for a coding bootcamp project. Currently, I am running into a problem with multer, or the process during which a file is uploading to my google "bucket." I can manually upload .flac files to Google buckets just fine and the file type stays as "audio/flac." I can send these files to the API for pretty accurate transcription. However, when sending files via my multipart form and an async function uploadFile, objects will be uploaded to Google buckets as "audio/x-flac" and they cannot be played or transcribed. On my front end, users should see a form in which they can submit a .flac file. My question is, what steps do I need to take to make sure that the file remains "audio/flac" versus "audio/x-flac" when uploaded to a Google bucket?

Here is how that form works out on the frontend:

```
        method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="audio" name="filename" class="btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn">
    </form>
```

Here is how my backend looks:

```
//set the destination of the form uploads to disk storage
let mStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads")
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    //set the extension to the original extension from form input
    cb(null, file.fieldname + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    // cb(null, file.buffer)
  }
})

//initialize the upload variable
let uploads = multer({storage: mStorage})

//Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

router.post("/results", uploads.single("filename"),(req, res) => {
  console.log("post route hit");
  //get the input field from the user
  // console.log(req.file);
  let filename = req.file.filename;
  console.log(filename);
  const bucketName = 'voiceappbucket';
  async function uploadFile() {
    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(`./uploads/${filename}`, {
    gzip: true,
    metadata: {
      content_type : "audio/flac",
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
      uploadType: "multipart"      
    },
  });
  console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  res.redirect(`/${req.file.filename}`)
  }
  uploadFile().catch(console.error);
})
```

If anyone has had similar issues and successfully navigated them, I would love to hear from you. Feedback on my code or the way I have asked this question is appreciated since I'm new to the community! :-)